# Azure Function v2 google authentication with google

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-functions, azure-authentication

I have an **Azure Function app** with Log in with google (I only need google right now) and I cant authenticate correctly

[image: gooogle configured and log in with google on]

### Trial 1 :

1. I make a get request to my api : https://examplefunctions.azurewebsites.net/
2. Google authentication pop up
3. Enter my credentials
4. then I make a get request to https://examplefunctions.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me
5. I get an json with **access_token** and **id_token** and other properties like user_claims etc
6. then I go to postman
7. make an get request to an function that have **AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous** : https://examplefunctions.azurewebsites.net/api/myfunction
8. Enter the **access_token** in the autorization with OAuth 2.0
9. server return an 401 : You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
10. then replace the **access_token** with the **id_token** information in the autorization tab in post man and the server return the same.

After that do the following:

### Trial 2 :

1. go to https://examplefunctions.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google in the browser
2. Google authentication pop up
3. Enter my credentials
4. the server redirect to an url that have this property **authenticationToken**
5. I enter this authenticationToken in the OAuth2.0 in postman and return the same 401 : You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Then I do this and authenticate  :

### Trial 3 :

1. go to https://examplefunctions.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google in the browser
2. Google authentication pop up
3. Enter my credentials
4. the server redirect to an url that have this property **authenticationToken**
5. In the headers of post man I put **X-ZUMO-AUTH** with the value previusly receive in **authenticationToken** and voila the server response with an OK status with my expected json.

But here the problem in the trial 3 (the only one that works) I dont receive the claims. --> here I get a null `var claims = req.HttpContext.User.Claims;`

And I need the user google information. Another thing is That I dont want to login using a header like X-ZUMO-AUTH, I want to use the OAuth 2.0 standard.

I dont know why I cant access using the trial 1 and 2, because the server return me an token after i log in, this token seems useless.

I have been trying to make a good google authentication for a week and I cant, I need your help.

NOTE : I will consume this api with an angular, postman, xamarin or maybe flutter

Comment: Did you create the function from portal? I created a basic function from portal and trail 3 is working for me, it returns `stable_sid` and other claims successfully.
Perhaps trial 1 and 2 are not supported for function apps.
Do check [Azure Functions and App Service Authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2018/02/19/azure-functions-and-app-service-authentication/) for implementing google auth, and samples here [AzureFunctionsEasyAuth](https://github.com/stuartleeks/AzureFunctionsEasyAuth/blob/master/src/SimpleWebClient/Pages/vanilla-js.cshtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution!!!

The problem was that I was using the azure function autentication alone, but for a best practice autentication in azure, you need to convinate Azure B2C Active Directory Tenant with your azure function app

I followed thouse tutorials :

**Here you learn to configure the tenant**
https://youtu.be/a1s6LMXi7Xk

**Here with the previous learning you complete the Azure Functions authentication**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hmahrt/2017/03/07/azure-active-directory-b2c-and-azure-functions/

Now every user that log in to my app is registed in the B2C tenant and I can have more detail information of who is using my app and when is loging in, etc

Answer (score 0):

Last week there has been regression. Fix has been deployed. Customers will pick up the new behavior after a site restart (so may need to restart their sites if this does not occur organically).

Comment: I restart the app and the issue persist